# How to avoid fo:block thin/empty box printing at the bottom of page

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am writing an XSL-FO to generate PDF report.

In the PDF, I display some content inside a rectangular box using fo:block with border.

```
<fo:block border-width="0.5pt">.....</fo:block>
```

In some cases, when the box starts at the bottom of the page & if there is no enough place to print the content then a thin box is printed & in the next page a new box appears with content. Please refer the below image which explains my issue: [image]

fo:block has an attribute `keep-together.within-page="always"` which makes sure that if fo:block content doesn't fit in a page then pushes it to next page but this doesn't resolve my issue because it pushes the content down when half of the page is available to print & content doesn't fit which creates blank space in the page, which is not my requirement.

Is there anyway to avoid printing thin/empty box as shown in the image?

Comment: 1) What formatter are you using? and 2) you should past a sample of the XSL FO that does this. Why? Because it should not happen, it is possible you have some significant whitespace in the block at the start.

Comment: And I just Tested it with FOP and RenderX, neither exhibit this behavior for my structure. So your issue is impossible to diagnose without seeing the actual XSL FO you are producing. You have some structure in it inside the block that is causing whitespace.